# Why does my output show exponential results when my data type is double?

Tags: c, types

I am trying to find the average of 3 digits : 3.5 9.6 10.2 which are floating point numbers.

However I cannot understand why my output shows such a weird number.

```
/* Computes pairwise averages of three numbers */

#include <stdio.h>

double average(double a , double b )
{
    return (a + b)/2 ;
}

int main (void)
{
    double x, y,z;

    printf("Enter three numbers: ");
    scanf("%g%g%g", &x,&y,&z);
    printf("Average of %g and %g : %g\n", x,y,average(x,y));
    printf("Average of %g and %g : %g\n", y,z,average(y,z));
    printf("Average of %g and %g : %g\n", x,z,average(x,z));

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please look at the compiler warnings. *format string '%g' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double *'. Note: consider using '%lg' in the format string.*

Comment: Also, please make it routine to test the result of `scanf()` such as  `if(scanf("%g%g%g", &x,&y,&z) != 3) { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your valuable time and enable all compiler warnings to catch these simple errors.

`%g` expects a matching `float *`.
`%lg` expects a matching `double *`.

```
double x, y,z;
// scanf("%g%g%g", &x,&y,&z);
scanf("%lg%lg%lg", &x,&y,&z);
```

---

Better code also checks the `scanf()` return value

```
if (scanf("%lg%lg%lg", &x,&y,&z) == 3) Success();
```